# C++ Change Inherited Class

Tags: c++, polymorphism

So say i have the following

- Class A - Main Class(cannot change)
- Class B - Base Class
- Class C - Alternate Base Class

Class A is defined as

```
Class A : public Class B
{};
```

How would I go about changing it programatically so that it would instead be `Class A : public Class C`?

The reasoning being that I want Class C to be a stubbed out minimalistic version of Class B for Unit Testing purposes.  So i need a way to spawn a version of Class A, without modifying class A that then uses Class C's methods and not Class B.

Hopefully that makes sense?

Comment: The short answer is: you can't. C++ doesn't work this way.

Comment: That is not how a static type system works.

Comment: How about this. Name both classes `B`, but configure your project or build system to make sure one and only one of them is used.

Comment: This is not how a unit test works. You test B independently of A, and then test A independently of B. What B does inside of A should already be tested/verified, and A's behavior is what needs to be tested.

Comment: @rubenvb I agree, in this case B is a Hardware SDK we cannot alter that makes calls directly to hardware, A is a wrapper class we write to use these low level hardware functions to perform more advanced tasks.  I want to replace B with a "mock" set of functions that would talk to virtual hardware.  We wouldnt be able to validate the output of the hardware, but that is not our goal, our goal is to ensure that when a user types in SET HARDWARE OUTPUT that the appropriate bit 17 gets set.  We can use a dummy INT32 to do this.  The problem is that A is tied to B, and i want it tied to C for test.

Answer (score 1):

You can use templates and change it at compile-time:

```
template<typename T>
class AT: public T { /* ... */ };
```

Now, somewhere, you can do this:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
using A = AT<C>;
#else
using A = AT<B>;
#endif
```

Otherwise, if you want to do that at runtime, you should rather use composition over inheritance, as an example:

```
struct A {
    I subclass;
};

// ...

struct B: I {};
struct C: I {};
```

Doing this, you can introduce a trigger in your software that simply forces the injection of an instance of `B` or of `C` in your instance of `A`.
As long as the instance of `A` forwards it's requests to the underlying class, it doesn't matter what's the derived one, it matters its interface.

---

To reply to the actual question: you cannot change the type of the base class at runtime.
If `A` inherits from `B`, that's all.

Answer (score 0):

In light of your comment, there are several answers, but the real answer is to not use inheritance.

1. Use composition:

   ```
   class wrapper
   {
     thing_you_want_to_mock& thingie;

     // all the wrapped functionality
   };
   ```

   Here you can just create a mock `thing_you_want_to_mock`, and test the wrapper with the mock object. Problem here is that I'm assuming `thing_you_want_to_mock` has an overridable interface, which probably isn't the case for you.
2. Use templated composition:

   ```
   template<typename ThingYouWantToMock>
   class wrapper
   {
     ThingYouWantToMock thing;

     // Wrapper functions that call functions on thing
   };
   ```

Both are examples of the... Strategy Pattern! In some form or other.